# Qt4 vs JavaFX. which is better?

Tags: programming-languages, qt4, javafx

Which is better,  Qt4 or JavaFX?

I work for a startup. We built the first version using JavaFX. Now my superiors are suggesting a shift to Qt4.

Is it a good decision to shift?

Comment: This question is far to open-ended and lacking any useful details.

Comment: i'm sorry if my question was a vague... we are building a standalone desktop app... with no requirement of internet access... i built the same using javafx... i wanna know is i can achieve better results using QT, in terms of User Experience, functionality and packaging..

Comment: Download Qt 4, and run qtdemo application. If you can easily do that in javafx, then you don't need to switch.

Answer (score 2):

The question like this is too broad to answer meaningfully.

Qt4 and JavaFX have different goals.

- Qt4 is for writing cross-platform desktop applications
- JavaFX is for writing rich Internet applications

Qt4 allows for better desktop integration (drag&drop, playing nice with the configuration systems of different platforms, native look & feel, ...), so if you want a nice desktop app, use Qt4.

OTOH, Qt4 cannot be used for an Internet application (web app), so if that's what you want, use JavaFX. JavaFX can also be used for desktop apps, but it requires more compromises than a dedicated desktop GUI toolkit like Qt4.

So what are your requirements?

*Edit:*

Based on your comments:

Standalone desktop apps are not JavaFX's main goal, but if it works for you, I see no reason to change it.

You can write great applications using JavaFX, especially because you have access to all the stuff the JDK offers. As to system integration: While QT4 is better in this respect, Java already offers a lot (such as Swing an JDK 6's new system integration features). So if you don't intend to write something highly integrated (such as a Windows shell extension), JavaFx will be fine.

Comment: QtWebKit module is available for web apps in Qt..

Comment: QtWebKit let's you have an embedded browser in your app. Is not for creating a web app.

Comment: To cite Qt's docs: "QtWebKit provides a Web browser engine that makes it easy to embed content from the World Wide Web into your Qt application"

Comment: i'm sorry if my question was a vague... we are building a standalone desktop app... with no requirement of internet access... i built the same using javafx... i wanna know is i can achieve better results using QT, in terms of User Experience, functionality and packaging...